# How can I display the last message in exim4 mail queue?

Tags: linux, debian, exim, mail-transport-agent

How can I display the last message in `exim4` mail queue?

I, actually, want to get the last message ID in `exim` mail queue, to check if it's delivered, in the log file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use the command

```
exim -bp
```

you will get a list of all messages currently in the queue. If the message is still in the queue, it has not yet been delivered. If the message has already been delivered you will need to examine the exim_mainlog file to check for the last exim_id.

Comment: thanks for ur reply, actualy that's what i want to do, i'm using a java app to send message and  i want it to get  the last message id, so i can check in the mainlog, if it's delivered correctly, what i'm asking is there a command to get the last message id received by exim?

Comment: The exim command I pasted will show you all the messages in the queue from the oldest to the newest. So the last line in the list will be the most recent message. However if your server does not have a high volume of mail, the message could be delivered before you have a chance to catch it in the queue. When it is delivered there will no longer be an entry there.